# How to prove that a function is Riemann integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

> I am given the function
>
> $$ f : [−\pi/2, \pi/2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$

where

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
 1 & \text{if } \quad \sin(1/x) > 0, x \neq 0 \\
-1 & \text{if } \quad \sin(1/x) < 0, x \neq 0 \\
 0 & \text{if } \quad \sin(1/x) = 0, x \neq 0 \\
 0 & \text{if } \quad x = 0
\end{cases}$$

and I am asked if the function is Riemann integrable and why.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Perhaps look just before this problem in your textbook.  Is there some result there that might apply to this?  Since you did not reveal what textbook this is, we cannot help with that part.

Comment: Sorry about that. The problem is from a previous Calculus 3 exam. We don't really follow a particular textbook other than the professor's notes. We've studied **Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability** and 2 integrability criterions(In my notebook they are called 1 and 2 form of integrability) but I can't find them on the internet.

Comment: There are various definitions of Riemann integrability in use (all of them leading to the same class of admissible functions). Which one is yours?

Comment: We defined it with Darboux sums.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a powerful theorem which you may keep in mind:

> A function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$
>   if and only if it is bounded and the measure of the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure $0$.

So, with this in mind. Where is your function discontinuous?